# Pass individual elements of an array to a case statement in Ruby - LCD display numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, numbers, lcd, digital

I am trying to pass an array of numbers to a case statement.
For example: I ask the user to input a value, for example 12. Then I split it into an array [1,2]. I then pass it to my method case statement. My case statement is to output the digital format of 1 and 2.

My Issue:
I cannot get it to print more than an input of 1 element.
How can I output both the 1 and 2 as a digital number with 1 array? Or with a users input? Is my code far off?

My Code:

```
puts "Enter numbers between 0-9 up to 2 digits: "

x = gets.chomp
x = x.split('')

def digital_number(n)

digits = n

#Start case for digit input
  case digits
  when ["1"]
  puts " | "
  puts "   "
  puts " | "
  puts "   "
  puts n

  when ["2"]
  puts " - "
  puts "  |"
  puts " - "
  puts "|  "
  puts " - "

  else
  puts "That is not an available number."

  end
end

digital_number(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is your array of digits. You should pass each digit to `case` sequentially:

```
number = gets.chomp
digits = number.split('')

digits.each { |digit| digital_number(digit) }
```

And case the digits:

```
case digit
when '1'
  # ...
when '2'
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! was confused for a second because I was putting the .each function above my case. In my brain I thought of what you had put... but I don't think I was able to write it correctly before.

Comment: Would you know how I can output the digital numbers side by side now? Since it goes through each number and outputs it on a new line. Is there a way to space them horizontally? so its horizontally printing 1 2 instead of vertically 1, 2?

Comment: It's not possible if you print digits one by one. You can save each line to a variable, i.e., `when '1' lines[0] << ' | ' lines[1] << '   '` and so on (`lines` is an array of strings here), and then print it line by line, i.e., `lines.each { |line| puts line }`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Vasily Yudin's answer just with scan and the same as what he had also said in his comment.

```
puts "Enter numbers between 0-9 up to 2 digits: "

x = gets.chomp
@arr = []

def digital_number(n)

  #Start case for digit input
  case n
  when "1" 
    @arr << " | "
    @arr << " | "
    puts n

  when "2" 
    @arr << "-" 
    @arr << " |"
    @arr << "-" 
    @arr << "| "
    @arr << "-" 
  else
    puts "That is not an available number."
  end 
end

x.scan(/\w/).each{|d| digital_number(d)}
puts @arr.join(' ')
```

Comment: I think I have an idea to manipulate what you have given me. I will try it out and ill repost it if I get it right...

Comment: I upvoted people that helped out. But it says it can't be shown publically for under 15 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solves my problem. Can delete '#' for ARGV if you want to put in an argument to the code. But just for terminal use, we have gets.chomp. Thank you for your help. This solves my problem, even if it may not be the most efficient.

```
# Add an argument in the terminal and
# .to_s converts the argument into a string
# so that ".scan" can take a string argument

#x = ARGV.to_s

x = gets.chomp
puts "Arguments entered is between 0-9: #{x}"

#These are empty arrays that get added in the cases
@arr1 = []
@arr2 = []
@arr3 = []
@arr4 = []
@arr5 = []

def digital_number(n)

#Start case for digit input
case n

when "0"
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "| |"
@arr3 << "   "
@arr4 << "| |"
@arr5 << " - "

when "1"
@arr1 << "   "
@arr2 << " | "
@arr3 << "   "
@arr4 << " | "
@arr5 << "   "

when "2"
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "  |"
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "|  "
@arr5 << " - "

when '3'
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "  |"
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "  |"
@arr5 << " - "

when '4'
@arr1 << "   "
@arr2 << "| |"
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "  |"
@arr5 << "   "

when '5'
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "|  "
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "  |"
@arr5 << " - "

when '6'
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "|  "
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "| |"
@arr5 << " - "

when '7'
@arr1 << "-- "
@arr2 << "  |"
@arr3 << "   "
@arr4 << "  |"
@arr5 << "   "

when '8'
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "| |"
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "| |"
@arr5 << " - "

when '9'
@arr1 << " - "
@arr2 << "| |"
@arr3 << " - "
@arr4 << "  |"
@arr5 << " - "

else
  puts "That is not an available number."
end
end
# This part iterates the method for each numbers inputted
x.scan(/\w/).each{|d| digital_number(d)}

# Output #
puts "   "
puts @arr1.join(' ')
puts @arr2.join(' ')
puts @arr3.join(' ')
puts @arr4.join(' ')
puts @arr5.join(' ')
```